# Create MongoDb view contain find clause

Tags: mongodb

Imagine I have a collection named user with below fields
- name
- family
- age

and I want to create a view that return all users that are 19 and 21

Comment: how can I use find in db.createView ? @anttud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK let's start by adding some data to a `users` collection, lets have a few people at diffrent ages:

```
> db.users.insertMany([
...    { "name": "foo", age: 12 },
...    { "name": "bar", age: 19 },
...    { "name": "wibble", age: 20 },
...    { "name": "wobble", age: 21 }
... ]);
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f377fff"),
                ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378000"),
                ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378001"),
                ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378002")
        ]
}
```

We can then write a view on top of this collection using the `createView` method which takes in a aggregation pipeline:

```
> var pipelines = [ { "$match" : { "$or" : [ { "age" : 19 }, { "age" :21 } ] } } ];
> db.createView("users19and21", "users", pipelines);
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

If you want to test your pipeline out before creating the view you can just call the `aggregate` method on the `users` collection, for example:

```
> var pipelines = [ { "$match" : { "$or" : [ { "age" : 19 }, { "age" :21 } ] } } ];
> db.users.aggregate(pipelines);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378000"), "name" : "bar", "age" : 19 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378002"), "name" : "wobble", "age" : 21 }
```

Once we have our view we can just query it like a collection:

```
> db.users19and21.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378000"), "name" : "bar", "age" : 19 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bd18277289332325f378002"), "name" : "wobble", "age" : 21 }
```

More information on creating views in mongodb can be found on their documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
db.createView( "viewName", "collection", [
    { $match : { key : value } }
    ,...
    ,...
])
```